# PHP/Mysql conditional statements

Tags: php, mysql, conditional-statements, increment

I have a simple page/database setup where you can increment or decrement the point total for person A or person B.

I've gotten some help, throwing some things into their own function to clean things up. I'm new to php and mysql; reading over what I have I understand all the logic, I just can't figure out how to finish it off, in the sense that as it is now, any button will add a point; I need to get the Subtract point button working too.

My database is table 'user' with points and name within

Here's what I have:

```
<?php
function print_r_dump( $val )
{
echo '<pre>';
print_r( $val );
echo '</pre>';
}

//if ( isset( $_POST ) || isset( $_POST['Add point'] ) )
if ( isset( $_POST ) )
{

//Prints what's in post
print_r_dump( $_POST );

$str = "select * from user where name = '";
$str .= $_POST['person'];
$str .= "'";

$link = mysql_connect('mysql.xxxxx.net', 'xxxxx', 'xxxxx');
mysql_select_db('xxxxx_points', $link);
$result = mysql_query( $str , $link);

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ;
$points = $row['points'];

$str = 'update user set points = '. ($points+1) . ' where name = \''. $_POST['person'] . '\'';
$result = mysql_query( $str , $link);
}




$link = mysql_connect('mysql.xxxxx.net', 'xxxxx', 'xxxxx');
mysql_select_db('xxxxx_points', $link);

$str = "SELECT points FROM user WHERE name='Person A'" ;
$str = "SELECT * FROM user ";
$result = mysql_query( $str , $link);


$results = array();
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) )
{
$results[ $row['name'] ] = $row['points'];
}

?>

Person A's count: <?php echo $results['Person A']; ?>
<br>


<form method="post" action="index.php">
<input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="Add point" />
<input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="Subtract point" />
<input type="hidden" name="person" value="Person A" />
</form>

<br>

Person B's count: <?php echo $results['Person B']; ?>
<br>

<form method="post" action="index.php">
<input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="Add point" />
<input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="Subtract point" />
<input type="hidden" name="person" value="Person B" />
</form>

<?

print_r_dump( $results  );

?>
```

Comment: What's your question, and what are you expecting us to do it all for you?

Comment: Right now, either button increments the points. I need to differentiate so the subtract button decrements.

Comment: Show us the input form code please.

Comment: This is everything.. this is my index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you don't necessarily need the first SQL query either. You can use the current value in the database and have it update itself, as long as the points field is numeric and not a string, for example. Try this for the major PHP portion of your code.

```
<?php
function print_r_dump( $val )
{
echo '<pre>';
print_r( $val );
echo '</pre>';
}

if ( isset( $_POST ) )
{

//Prints what's in post
print_r_dump( $_POST );

$link = mysql_connect('mysql.xxxxx.net', 'xxxxx', 'xxxxx');
mysql_select_db('xxxxx_points', $link);

$str = "";

    if ($_POST['submit_button']=='Add point')
    {
    $str = 'update user set points = points+1 where name = \''. $_POST['person'] . '\'';
    }
    else if ($_POST['submit_button']=='Subtract point')
    {
    $str = 'update user set points = points-1 where name = \''. $_POST['person'] . '\'';
    }
    if ($str)
    {
    $result = mysql_query( $str , $link);
    }
}

$str = "SELECT points FROM user WHERE name='Person A'" ;
$str = "SELECT * FROM user ";
$result = mysql_query( $str , $link);


$results = array();
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) )
{
$results[ $row['name'] ] = $row['points'];
}

?>
```

Comment: The only thing I don't understand is the line where you use 'Person A' Can you explain how you use them there, but aren't using Person B elsewhere? Is it sort of, if not A then everything else since we only have one other option?

Comment: If you mean the line ($str = "SELECT points FROM user WHERE name='Person A'" ;) I just left that in there because you had it. That line doesn't do anything because the next line ($str = "SELECT * FROM user ";) overwrites it and selects all data from the user table. You could take out the line with Person A, I just thought you had some debugging purpose for it.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of errors:

- You don't need to create new link
  every time you run query.
- This line is not safe at all: $str .= $_POST['person']; any one can hack
  your code.
- You should check if your results (returned from mysql) are valid.

I tried to clean it up a bit. There might be few errors here and there (I didn't test), but demonstrate what I just said:

```
<?php
function print_r_dump( $val )
{
echo '<pre>';
print_r( $val );
echo '</pre>';
}
$link = mysql_connect('mysql.xxxxx.net', 'xxxxx', 'xxxxx');
mysql_select_db('xxxxx_points', $link);


if ( isset( $_POST ) )
{
$str = "select * from user where name = '";
$str .= $_POST['person'];
$str .= "'";

$result = mysql_query( $str , $link);

if($result) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ;
    $points = $row['points'];
    if(condition for adding) { // probably if(isset($_POST[submit_button_add))
        $str = 'update user set points = '. ($points+1) . ' where name = \''. $_POST['person'] . '\'';
        $result = mysql_query( $str , $link);
    } else if(condition for subtracting){// probably if(isset($_POST[submit_button_sub))
        $str = 'update user set points = '. ($points-1) . ' where name = \''. $_POST['person'] . '\'';
        $result = mysql_query( $str , $link);
    }
    $str = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE 1";
    $result = mysql_query( $str , $link);
    if($result) {
        $results = array();
        while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) )
        {
            $results[ $row['name'] ] = $row['points'];
        }
    }
}

?>

Person A's count: <?php echo $results['Person A']; ?>
<br>


<form method="post" action="index.php">
<input type="submit" name="submit_button_add" value="Add point" />
<input type="submit" name="submit_button_sub" value="Subtract point" />
<input type="hidden" name="person" value="Person A" />
</form>

<br>

Person B's count: <?php echo $results['Person B']; ?>
<br>

<form method="post" action="index.php">
<input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="Add point" />
<input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="Subtract point" />
<input type="hidden" name="person" value="Person B" />
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, I know this code is not secure whatsoever, but this will not be a public or known page. Shared amongst just a handful of people. Let me check this out..

Comment: I can't figure out the conditional statements..

if ( isset($_POST[submit_button] == 'Add point') )

is what I came up with..

Comment: It is better not to use those spaces when you name something... Instead of using Add Point, add_point is easier. The reason is spaces are handled in different ways in different layers.

Comment: The idea was as both of your buttons have the same name but returns different value, you check the values, I would say instead using different name and check if any of them was clicked using isset()